# SQL - Opening a SCROLL CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I am trying to run an executable in which I have a regular CURSOR and a SCROLL CURSOR looking at a single table. The CURSOR serves to keep track of an outer loop while the SCROLL CURSOR aids in an inner loop. When I try to run the program, it seems as though the code gets stuck trying to open the SCROLL CURSOR (e.g. it will print 'OK' but not 'CODE DOES NOT REACH HERE'). I am using SQL 2008 R2. I have tried running a very scaled back version of my code and it appears that I cannot even open a SCROLL CURSOR in any circumstance on my computer so I am wondering if it is some weird compatability isssue or I somehow have the wrong syntax (even though it is straightforward). For what its worth, in testing my code I have been able to open a SCROLL CURSOR on another computer.

Do you have any ideas what may be causing this? I have copied below the code I am trying to run (pseudo code for the declaration of all the variables). Thanks in advance.

```
create proc expiration_exec2

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE bunch of @variables
...

DECLARE cursor_main CURSOR FOR
SELECT Member_ID,redeemed_month,activity_month,tenure_month,min_pts,expired_pts,closed_pts,tenure_quarter,enrollment_month
FROM HIST_TRIANGLE

OPEN cursor_main
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_main
INTO @account,@r_month,@e_month,@tenure_month,@min_pts,@expired_pts,@closed_pts,@tenure_quarter,@enrollment_month

DECLARE cursor_secondary CURSOR SCROLL FOR
SELECT Member_ID,redeemed_month,activity_month,min_pts,expired_pts,closed_pts
FROM HIST_TRIANGLE

PRINT 'OK'

OPEN cursor_secondary
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_secondary
INTO @account2,@r_month2,@e_month2,@min_pts2,@expired_pts2,@closed_pts2

PRINT 'CODE DOES NOT REACH HERE'

...

Bunch more code
```

Answer (score 0):

First pass...try putting a 'BEGIN' after 'AS' and adding 'END' after 'bunch more code'...that may be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please put cursor type while declaring the cursor. As it may be possible that the cursor you have declared take Static Read only type as default.

please check below link for more details: 
[Default type of SQL Server Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567633/default-type-of-sql-server-cursor)