# Default type of SQL Server Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Just have a really quick question regarding SQL Server cursors. If you declare a cursor with all the default options, does it default to `FORWARD_ONLY DYNAMIC` cursor? Here is the snippet from MSFT documentation:

> FORWARD_ONLY
>   Specifies that the cursor can only be scrolled from the first to the last row. FETCH NEXT is the only supported fetch option. **If FORWARD_ONLY is specified without the STATIC, KEYSET, or DYNAMIC keywords, the cursor operates as a DYNAMIC cursor.** When neither FORWARD_ONLY nor SCROLL is specified, **FORWARD_ONLY is the default**, unless the keywords STATIC, KEYSET, or DYNAMIC are specified. STATIC, KEYSET, and DYNAMIC cursors default to SCROLL. Unlike database APIs such as ODBC and ADO, FORWARD_ONLY is supported with STATIC, KEYSET, and DYNAMIC Transact-SQL cursors.

So putting these 2 "bolded" statements together, is my assumption correct?

Thanks

Comment: I'll just put this in the comments... If you're using a cursor, you're probably doing it wrong.  If you're using something other than a FAST_FORWARD cursor, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: Adding to what @DaveMarkle said, "probably wrong" means 90% probability. SQL (in all databases) can process millions of records using advanced computation and IO algorithms in  seconds. Cursors force it to process each record one at a time, eradicating any performance gain. There are set-based techniques to address almost any scenario where people think they need cursors. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I agree set-based approach is definitely the way to go, and I generally stay away from cursors however in this case, its a one-off cleanup script i had to write with 20 different scenarios possible, with all the logging/auditing options, which I had a few hours to put together, and also working with a very small dataset (20k rows).  Performance is not a concern in this case (runs in under 20 sec).  I was just curious, as I had a general discussion with a colleague, as to the locking and default autocommit behaviour in cursors.

Comment: Also to add to my comment, I know different type of cursors behave differently in terms of locking the dataset loaded in the cursor.  So the discussion we had with a colleague was whether the cursor places everything in one transaction automatically and locks the dataset for the duration of that transaction until the cursor is closed, while I believe that a dynamic cursor would lock records as it fetches them and holds the lock until the next fetch or the cursor is closed, whichever is first.  Since i am using the default cursor options I was wondering if it creates dynamic cursor by default.

Comment: If you have *specific* requirements for your cursor, why not just be explicit rather than cut down on typing 20 characters if the default happens to match what you would have asked for explicitly?

Comment: Thats a valid point :)  Its just whenever I resorted to using cursors (for one-off scripts and very small datasets), I used the default most of the time, so just started wondering recently what exactly the default was.

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [page you quoted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms180169) actually describes what the default is, but it's not very clear. If you permit an answer that cheats:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT 1;
SELECT properties FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@spid);
```

On my system this yields `TSQL | Snapshot | Read Only | Global (0)`. The documentation on [sys.dm_exec_cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190346) explains how to decode this. In this case, it's a `GLOBAL STATIC READ_ONLY` cursor.

The default depends on what your cursor is *for*, however. This:

```
CREATE TABLE #a (a INT);
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #a;
SELECT properties FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@spid);
```

Yields `TSQL | Dynamic | Optimistic | Global (0)`, in other words a `GLOBAL DYNAMIC OPTIMISTIC` cursor.

The moral of this story is probably that you shouldn't rely on the defaults; there's no good reason to unless, for some reason, you must adhere to the ANSI syntax and cannot specify any options. If that's the case, you're looking at database-agnostic code that's using cursors, which is a truly frightening prospect indeed.

Comment: Thanks! That helps.  So then it seems that the default is depended on the cursor dataset, which could probably explain why there is no definite statement as to what the default is from MSFT.

Comment: @fed1999: the page actually does describe what the defaults are, but you have to put together a *lot* of facts and read the description of every single option, just about. I didn't feel it necessary to quote the entire thing.